# Want to run several db.query() method in parallel without getting any error

Tags: node.js, orientdb, orientjs

I am using Node JS . I am a beginner. I use OrientJS to connect orientdb from Node JS. I want to run several db.query() method in parallel. This queries are formed  by reading a large text file using line-by-line module.

For example,

```
var queryForGeoUpdate = 'update (' +
    '\nselect  from (' +
    "\n  select expand(outE('GeoAgentSummary')) " +
    '\n  from Agent ' +
    '\n  where name = "' + name + '" and number = \'' + number + "' and type = '" + type + "'" +
    "\n) where in.name  = '" + Geo + "'" +
    '\n)  increment _' + FiscalYear + ' = ' + TMSSalesAllocatedBookingsNet + 'f,  _' +
    FiscalPeriodID + ' = ' + TMSSalesAllocatedBookingsNet +
    'f, _' + FiscalQuarterID + ' = ' + TMSSalesAllocatedBookingsNet + 'f'

  // console.log(queryForGeoUpdate)
  db.query(queryForGeoUpdate) // query and db call for Country ends here
```

like db.query(queryForGeoUpdate) there are seven queries like db.query(queryForRegionUpdate) and so on...

if I run it asynchronously "process out of memory occurrs". If I run it synchronously it takes too much time. How can I solve it within very less time..

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: It will be really difficult to improve performance with large text files being read line-by-line.

Comment: How do you run now them in sync and async way?

Comment: But, Oleksandr Gubchenko I have to read it line-by-line. Because I get that data for the variables namely Geo, Theater etc from each line, made the query to the database, again read line to compute the values of the variables and make query to the Database and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with the DB you are using. If you are sure the DB works "correctly" and the calls you make are correct (e.g. if there isn't a way to make you queries much smaller) you could try running with:

node --max_old_space_size="memmory in MB, try something large like 8192" app.js

It seems rather strange that a DB query would run out of memory thought... I always assumed queries are, generally speaking,a  lot more CPU intensive and require relatively little memory.

For these sort of large queries you might also try spawning separate processes:

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: Thanks, for your answer.

Comment: But, Today I checked that OrientDB  supports only 1000 concurrent connections. When it  cross that limit it just rejects any connection. But I don't know how to check number of total connection to orientdb at any instant of time using OrientJS. If I can check then I can find a way out. Any help is appreciated

Comment: If you run out of available connections, this means the client never closes them, anyway you can ajust the number in the config file.